# Adding a .load() method to the function stops the function from working the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

What it does is it removes/adds the class of an element on click. More specifically, it makes a div slide in from the side by changing its class on click. This works fine, but after I added the `.load()` method, I can't close it (remove its class). I can open the div just fine the first time, but it won't `toggleClass` the second time, unless I remove the class by other means.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: whats your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing the HTMl of inner-container with load function thus cart-container-toggle is not availabale any more for click function to work